# How to use VLOOKUP function for a column which value is generated from another two column

Tags: excel-formula

I want to populate this formulae but this level of nested loop are not allowed...

```
=IF(D2<101,"27.50",IF(D2<151,"21.34",IF(D2<201,"26.07",IF(D2<251,"29.81",IF(D2<301,"34.54",IF(D2<351,"39.27",IF(D2<401,"44.00",IF(D2<451,"49.72",IF(D2<501,"56.87",IF(D2<551,"61.60",IF(D2<601,"66.33",IF(D2<651,"71.06",IF(D2<701,"75.90",IF(D2<751,"80.63",IF(D2<801,"85.36",IF(D2<851,"87.67",IF(D2<901,"90.97",IF(D2<951,"92.40","97.90"))))))))))))))))))
```

where D2 is calculated like `=(A2+B2)/2`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `INDEX(MATCH())` to solve your issue, but the order of lookup array must be descending, and your limits should be `+1` as it works in greater than or equal to form, so if this is the lookup table:

```
A   B
252 29.81
202 26.07
152 21.34
102 27.5
```

This will be the formula:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$B$4,MATCH(D2,$A$1:$A$4,-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to go about this is to use a lookup table as a half-way point, either somewhere on the sheet or in hidden cells/sheet if preferred.

The table will look something like this:

```
|-----|-------|
| 101 | 27.5  |
|-----|-------|
| 151 | 21.34 |
|-----|-------|
| 201 | 26.07 |
|-----|-------|
 etc...
```

Then you can use a lookup to find the value based on the condition, let's say this table is in `Sheet2!A1:B3`:

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$3,SMALL(IF($D$2<Sheet2!$A$1:$A$3,ROW(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$3)-ROW(Sheet2!$A$1)+1),1)),"97.90")` - Entered as an array formula (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>)

`INDEX(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$3,` - Create a 1 based index (index starting from 1) of B1:B3

`IF($D$2<Sheet2!$A$1:$A$3,ROW(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$3)-ROW(Sheet2!$A$1)+1` - Returns a reference to the position of the all items in A1:A3 that are larger than D2 as an array (by taking the row number minus the row number of the first row plus 1)

`SMALL([If()],1)` - Return the first, smallest row number from the array that `INDEX()` then looks for

`IFERROR([Index(Small(If()))],"97.90")` - As any number greater than the largest number in the table will produce an error, then return "97.90" instead

Comment: Ascending order will return bad result, for instance if you lookup `105` you'd get `27.5`, thus the lookup table needs to be descending and `MATCH` should have `-1` as the `match type`.